# Would your soul be torn if you killed somebody without using Unforgivable Curses?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse, hp-methods-of-rationality

Some ideas are taken from HPMOR.

**Kill through intentional spell**: If you are a magician, and you kill somebody with a cutting curse, severing his head, he's dead. If you sever the torso, he dies due to bloodloss. If you use a levitating spell on somebody and you bring him up high enough and break the spell, he will die from the fall. If he's soaked in oil/gas, and you do an 'Incendio', he may very well die from the burns.

Would any of these cases tear your soul?

- **Kill through intention**: If you just get a gun and shoot somebody in the head, he will die (Sirius Black killed a lot of muggles this way). Would your soul be torn?
- **Kill through accident**: And last, if you accidentally confounded ingredients in Potions Class and the teacher wasn't paying enough attention and your cauldron got transformed into a bomb, supposing you somehow survived, would your soul be torn?

Comment: Sirius Black did not kill ANY muggle... where did you get the idea with the gun from? I do not remember having read anything about guns in any of the books... And "damage" to your souls is not the same as tearing it apart... damage is done on every kill... tearing apart only works with the preparations needed for Horcruxes...

Comment: @TorstenLink The only thing that could make think that Sirius killed anyone with a gun is at the beginning of tome 3, when he just escaped and muggle news say he has a gun and he's dangerous. But after verification, he never killed anyone, even less with a gun

Comment: Is this a question about the fanfiction or the main series?

Comment: If you're referring to HPMOR, the entire mechanism for creating horcruxes is different from what you're describing. Additionally it never says Sirius killed muggles with a gun in that fanfic either (though he did kill muggles).

Comment: I think I can remember that in the series, it was a news that Sirius Black killed a few muggles (10 or 11 if memory doesn't fail me) with a gun after he "killed" Peter Petigrew.

Comment: It was fake "muggle news": Peter blew up a whole street and a lot of muggles were killed... But ministerium of magic wanted them to fear Black. And as can't tell them: "beware, he is a dangerout wizard", they just told them: "Beware, he has a gun and has already killed with it"...

Comment: HP6 - Chapter: The knight bus: `While Muggles have been told that Black is carrying a gun
(a kind of metal wand which Muggles use to kill each other),
the magical community lives in fear of a massacre like that of
twelve years ago, when Black murdered thirteen people with a
single curse.`

Comment: Same page, later: `Black took out ’is wand and ’e blasted ’alf the street apart, an’ a wizard got it, an’ so did a dozen Muggles what got in
the way.`

Comment: Why the downvotes in the question? I think it was a fair doubt.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the soul can be torn apart by EVERY kind of murder.
We only learn from book 6 that someone can rip apart their soul, and it does nowhere state anything about only being able to rip it using an Unforgivable Curse.

Here is the part where we learn about this:

> “How do you split your soul?”
>
> “Well,” said Slughorn uncomfortably, “you must understand that the soul is supposed to remain intact and whole. Splitting it is an act of violation, it is against nature.”
>
> “But how do you do it?”
>
> “By an act of evil — the supreme act of evil. **By commiting murder. Killing rips the soul apart**. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would use the damage to his advantage: He would encase the torn portion —”
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Chapter 23 - Horcruxes</sub>

As you can see: No restriction on killing by using the Unforgivable Curses...
But: As killing through accident will not count as "murder" I think we can rule this out...

Comment: What about accidental murder?

Comment: See the quote: It needs a "supreme act of evil"... would you call an accident a "supreme act of evil"? In Germany anything accidential is not even called murder. We have two completely different words for it: murder = Mord, accidential murder = Totschlag, so no chance to mix them up here. The intent is what distinguishes them and I can imagine that the same thing is true for splitting the soul...

Answer (score -3):

## In HPMOR, any murder will do.

There are actually 2 versions of the Horcrux spell in HPMOR.

The first uses the burst of magic that might become a ghost, and channeling that through the caster. This version doesn't have special requirements on the murder circumstances.

The second is a sacrificial ritual, which, apparently Voldemort did anytime he murdered someone in private. So there is likely a spell and a murder involved, but we don't get the details, but unforgivable curses aren't mentioned.

Answer (score -5):

Soul damage seems to be always related to Unforgivable Curses, not to the act of killing. To kill someone is something that inevitably damages your soul, no matter if you are a Muggle or a wizard, no matter if you do it willingly or by accident. To kill anyone is something that burden any soul.

But use of the Unforgivable Curses like Cruciatus, even though you don't kill anyone with them, will damage your soul at a different level, on a magic way. Obviously, the damage is more severe the worse is the effect you are creating through your curses, as it's not the same to apply Cruciatus for just a couple of seconds to an enemy than apply it to hundreds of innocent victims until they get definitively mad.

Comment: Can you prove your statements with anything from the books? As written they seem to be highly speculative and only your own opinion...

Comment: "To kill anyone is something that burden any soul" is not, or shouln't be, an opinion, it should be a fact. If it isn't maybe our society have reached a point of no return. The fact that Uforgivable curses damage the soul is stated several times along the books, I don't have them at hand, but I'm pretty confident on it.